# Change color of certain chart points

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, colors, charts

I have a problem changing color in a chart. Following code:

```
chart1.Series["Test"].Color = Color.Red;
int start = array1.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series["Test"].Points.Count; i++)
{
      if (i >= start)
          chart1.Series["Test"].Points[i].Color = Color.Green;
      chart1.Series["Test"].Points.AddXY(x_axis[i], y_axis[i]);

}

chart1.Series["Test"].Points.DataBindXY(x_axis, y_axis);
chart1.Series["Test"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
```

the case: I have two arrays - one for the x-axis and one for the y-axis. Let's say they have length 32. I have another array (not important) with length of 12. Now I want that my graph changes the color after the 12th point. How can I do that? The code above doesn't work. The graph stays in one color.

Comment: How can `i < chart1.Series[""].Points.Count;` in your loop work. Is there a series with empty name?

Comment: sorry for that - edited

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I had to loop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
                {
                    chart1.Series["Test"].Points[i].Color = Color.Blue;

                }
```

the chart had to be bound first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many points are in your series while executing the loop and where they come from but by the `DataBindXY` method all the previous datapoints are removed and the new bound datapoints are created in automatic color (As I understand the working of DataBind)

Maybe you should try looping over the datapoints after the DataBindXY and "post-color" the points.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color for some data points by repeating loop for each data point after binding your data.

```
Points pts = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Points)series.Points(Type.Missing);
 foreach (Point pt in pts) { if(yourcondition) {
    pt.Border.Color = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbDarkOrange;
    pt.MarkerBackgroundColor = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbDarkOrange;
    pt.MarkerForegroundColor = (int)XlRgbColor.rgbDarkOrange;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition if you want to highlight (red) only some data in your chart you can use something like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            string test = chartLeaderBoard.Series["Active Tasks Count"].Points[i].XValue.ToString();

            if (test == selectedUser)
            {
                chartLeaderBoard.Series["Active Tasks Count"].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                chartLeaderBoard.Series["Active Tasks Count"].Points[i].Color = Color.Blue;
            }            
        }
```

in my case string selectedUser = dataGridViewLiderBoard.Rows[currentRow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

As the chart is based on the datagridview, where I do some additional things to get it.